# Meaning of "…as well had it not been for the machinations of journalists"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I've found the [article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/08/28/who-owns-the-internet) written with advanced writing skill and it is way harder to understand for me. I want to know the simplified meaning of sentence in the context that I'm giving you. Can you deconstruct and convert it into understandable one.

The following part of the sentence confused me so much. The way of writing and structuring it doesn't seem that ordinary. (like after *as well*, *had* is coming with *it* and *not been* )

Please help me to understand

***as well had it not been for the machinations of journalists***

You can see the full sentence below

> ...And he might have lost the Electoral College as well had it not
> been for the machinations of journalists working in the shady corners
> of what’s been called “the Victorian Internet.”

Comment: Welcome to ELU. **Which part** of the sentence are you particularly having trouble with? Perhaps "had it not been for"? Surely not "He might have lost the Electoral College as well". Please [edit] your question to narrow it down and show what you have already looked up (so people don't provide information you already know).

Comment: I've re-edited the question for becoming more obvious.

Comment: OK... but "as well" belongs to "He might have lost the Electoral College as well" (and could easily have a comma after it).

Comment: Okay the journalists were doing ABC. If they had not done ABC, he might have lost. But he didn't, because of ABC.

Comment: "As well", in this sense, basically means "also".

Comment: Correct parse: And he might have lost the Electoral College as well// had it not been for the machinations of journalists working in the shady corners of what’s been called “the Victorian Internet.”

Comment: I like that magazine, but I don't think it's for beginners.  Maybe it will be easier to read after another year or so of study of English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string of words you posted

> - *as well had it not been for the machinations of journalists*

is not a constituent, so it's not surprising you're puzzled. The *as well* part at the beginning just means "additionally" in the first clause

- *He might have lost the Electoral College as well*,

meaning "as well as" some loss previously mentioned. The next part is the explanation of why  he didn't lose the Electoral College as well

- *had it not been for ... journalists*

meaning *if it had not been for ...* This construction is a negative inversion, not uncommon but fairly formal.

If you learn where constituents stop and start, you will have less difficulty than if you treat words like beads on a string.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you posted is grammatically correct, but poorly written. It is wordy and a comma after "as well" would help with readability. The sentence means *He might have lost the Electoral College if journalists had not interfered.*